# Como obtengo el path o la ruta principal del proyecto en c#?

Tags: c#, rutas

Como obtener el path de un proyecto en c#.

`Application.StartupPath` no me da la ruta indicada

```
string ruta = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, @"json\SemanticaColores.json");
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Realmente necesito hacer referencias a unos archivos `json` dentro de la carpeta `json`, pero con obtener dicha ruta podría movilizarme por cualquier carpeta del proyecto

Comment: ¿Puedes incluir un ejemplo de código de lo que harías después de obtener la ruta del archivo? También, ¿puedes confirmar que el contenido del archivo nunca cambia? Porque dependiendo de lo que necesitas hacer, tal vez sea preferible agregar el archivo json como un recurso en tu proyecto y que lo leas como tal.

Answer (score 1):

[`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.basedirectory(v=vs.110).aspx) te dará la ruta donde esta situada el archivo dll, mayormente la carpeta `bin/`.

Si deseas navegar hacia atrás en la carpeta, entonces en combinación con [`Path.Combine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine(v=vs.110).aspx) puedes lograrlo:

```
var jsonFolder = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"..\json\SemanticaColores.json");
```

Esto te dará por ejemplo `C:/projecto/json/SemanticaColores.json`.